# Forwarding data traffic in android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have two android phones A & B which are connected using WiFiDirect and device A alone is connected to the internet through WiFi.
Can I forward all the internet traffic from device B to A and then forward them using A's internet connection and get the response for the requests and forward them back to B??

Is there any way to implement this programmatically in android??

Comment: So you want device A to be connected through WiFi and have device B connected throught WiFi to device A? Making device A both connected to WiFi and being a hotspot, giving internet to both devices throught device A?

Comment: B is connected to A using wifip2p. A will be connected to the internet using normal wifi connection. B can access the internet thru A by using WifiDirect. 

My idea is to make a device access internet thru wifi and act as a router to other devices using wifi hotspot..since wifi and wifihotspot cant be enabled simultaneously  i thot of this...

Comment: Ok good, because as you said a device cannot be hotspot and connected at the same time. That apart, I'm not aware a a way to set that configuration programmatically, sorry.

Comment: ok...read a lot about this and the best possible implementation seems to be writing a custom device driver..Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Make sure to share your solution if you end up somewhere by yourself, your question is interesting.

Comment: I read that wifidirect creates a new wifi interface with a different macid. And using the group info(AP name & password) any device with wifi capability can connect to our device.

Now the problem is I don't know how to set up IP tables to route traffic from WifiDirect's interface to the Wifi interface...any help??